# disabling asserts in production environment using nodejs

Tags: node.js, assert

I'm writing a nodejs project. using latest nodejs v0.12.7

I have tons of assert in my code. 
I want them to be removed in production environment.

Is there a way to have a flag if i want to call asserts or not ?

is there some other util i can use instead of asserts that allows me to disable in production environment ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

I put this middleware in my app.js

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send(err.message);
});
```

If you want you may just call send without params and no error would be sent to the requestor.